# Is organic chemistry mechanisms limited to organic chemistry?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am curious to know the mechanism of each reaction. Organic chemistry is satisfying for me because there is a mechanism behind each reaction which make a sense but when I Google for the mechanism of inorganic reaction I do not find any good results. I applied an organic reaction mechanism on an inorganic reaction and it worked as shown in the picture. By summarizing "Can we apply organic reaction mechanisms to inorganic reactions?"[image]

Comment: Is it a stupid question?...lemme know to delete it.

Comment: It would be nice to see your proposed mechanism (try to reduce image size or try VPN if your ISP is known for blocking stuff), but in general the question boils down to what makes sense and what doesn't. Mechanisms work fine for molecular substances, but are quirky when one tries to use them for network solid, which prevail in inorganic chemistry. BTW there is an entire book devoted to the mechanisms in inorganic chemistry: [Ghosh and Berg's  *Arrow pushing in inorganic chemistry*](https://doi.org/10.1002/9781118924525).

Comment: If I were you, I would refrain from assuming your question is stupid. If you did the research and gave it a good thinking, but you still cannot come up with the solution or rationalization, it is stupid *not* to ask.

Comment: Related: [Inorganic chemistry reaction mechanisms](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10959).

Comment: Actually I googled a lot and can not found anything related...so I thought maybe my question is soo easy that there is no need to answer it.

Comment: @andselisk uploading still not working...By the way it was the reaction of CO2 + H2O -----> H2CO3

Comment: Mechanism: H+ attacks on CO2 ...carbocation HCO2^+ formation occur....in the 2nd step OH^- attacks on carbocation and leads to the formation of H2CO3....Can you please input mechanism in my question by editing it?

Comment: My gut feeling says that we can apply organic reaction mechanisms to discrete molecules reaction in inorganic.

Comment: You should be able to it by yourself. If you still cannot sort out image uploading, just append the comments to your question by [edit]ing.

Comment: I approved the edit, but I think you should really check what's going on with your device or internet provider. Probably clear the cache and delete cookies for *.stackexchange.com site, then log back in.

Comment: I am using stack exchange app

Comment: Official SE app for Android hasn't been updated in 2.5 years and doesn't support many features, see e.g. [Meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/undefined-control-sequence-pu-in-official-se-android-app), so I would recommend *not to use the app* and stick with the web browser.

Comment: Mechanisms of hydrolysis, of certain common reactions and of organometallic compounds is known to me. But i mostly mug up the reactions

Comment: @andselisk bundle of thanks for  recommendation.